# Convert .NET timestamp

Tags: datetime, autohotkey

Anyone know what sort of timestamp this is?
130580051014610352

I believe it's ticks since 1970 or something, common in .NET.

I need to convert it to YYYYMMDDHH24MISS timestamp in AutoHotkey.

Appreciate any help

Comment: Are you working in .NET? you did not tag a language. It's probably [Epoch](http://www.epochconverter.com/) convertible in may language, aka `Sun, 26 Jul 2015 16:03:37 GMT`

Comment: No, I work in Autohotkey. Though this timestamp is made in a .NET application. Result should be about 17/10/2014 according to created time.

Comment: This site does the conversion correctly: http://tickstodatetime.com/

Comment: It looks to me like the site returned `0414-10-17​T07:38:21.462Z` that sure is in the past.

Comment: Tick (from filename): 130824030856564401
File created time (from windows): 26.07.2015 18:51
TicksToDatetime: 0415-07-26​T16:51:25.657Z

Date is correct, but year should be 2015, not 0415 @hoss

Answer (score 1):

It would appear to be a [Windows file time](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms724290.aspx).  Quoting MSDN:

> A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).

However, keep in mind that the file system where you obtained this timestamp is important.

- NTFS properly stores file times based on the UTC time.
- FAT16 and FAT32 store file times based on the *local* time.

  - This can be a problem if (for example) you save a file to a thumbdrive on one computer, then load it from another in a different time zone.
  - It can also be problematic within a single timezone because local times can't disambiguate between values that are in a daylight saving time fall-back transition period.

Assuming the value came from NTFS and is therefore UTC-based, you can get the UTC time in .NET code by using `DateTime.FromFileTimeUtc`, or you can get the equivalent local time by using `DateTime.FromFileTime`.

I'm not sure exactly what the equivalent code would be in AutoHotkey's scripting language, but I did notice that it already has a [built-in function](http://ahkscript.org/docs/commands/FileGetTime.htm) for getting a timestamp from a file, if that's what you're doing.

Answer (score 0):

Someone posted a solution in AHK forums:

```
TicksToTime(FileTicks,UTC="")
{ ; 64-bit value representing the number of 100-nanosecond intervals since January 1, 1601 (UTC)
    ; FileTicks := 131817689607677716
    FileSeconds := FileTicks // 10000000
    DateTimeUTC := 1601
    DateTimeUTC += FileSeconds, S
    if (UTC = 1)
        Return DateTimeUTC
    ; LocalTicks := FileTimeToLocalFileTime(FileTicks) ;;;
    VarSetCapacity(FileTime, 8, 0)
    VarSetCapacity(LocalTime, 8, 0)
    NumPut(FileTicks, FileTime, "UInt64")
    DllCall("FileTimeToLocalFileTime", "Ptr", &FileTime, "Ptr", &LocalTime)
    FileSeconds := (NumGet(LocalTime, "UInt64") // 10000000)
    DateTimeLoc := 1601
    DateTimeLoc += FileSeconds, S
    ;utc time = DateTimeUTC
    Return DateTimeLoc
}
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users learn and eventually apply that knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.